# Ffmpeg: how to get information about rawvideo encoder

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, encoding

For example, when i type:
`ffmpeg -h encoder=ffv1`
I have information about supported pixel formats:

> Supported pixel formats: yuv420p yuva420p yuva422p yuv444p (...)

and settings:

> ffv1 encoder AVOptions: -slicecrc E..V....... Protect slices with CRCs
> (default auto) -coder E..V....... Coder type (from -2 to 2) (...)

But when i type `rawvideo` instead of `ffv1` I have this:

> Encoder rawvideo [raw video]: General capabilities: dr1 threads
> Threading capabilities: frame

and that is all. No pixel formats, no setting. Does anyone know how to get info about supported pixel formats of rawvideo encoder?

ffmpeg version `6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev`

Comment: I don't know what you want to "fix" here. That's what's documented and you can only report it as a bug or submit a patch: https://www.ffmpeg.org/developer.html#Contributing

Comment: It's rawvideo. It supports everything.

Comment: thank you for letting me know